# MTOM not working after upgrading from weblogic 11g to 12c

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c, mtom

I have a web service that a user can ask for a document using the documents id as input. It is implemented this way, except that the example is for upload:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV143

My WebService implementation class:

```
@HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=false, memoryThreshold=4000000L)
@MTOM(threshold=3072)
@WebService(name="MyServicePortType",
    serviceName="MyService",
    targetNamespace="http://my.services.example.com")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService, Serializable {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsctx;

private MyRemote ejbRemote;
private EJBClientHelper ejbClientHelper;

public ElkomImpl() {
    ejbClientHelper = new EJBClientHelper();
}

@WebMethod
public @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") DataHandler fetchDocument( @WebParam(name = "reference")String reference) {
    SOAPFault soapFault = null;
    Logger log = ApplicationLogFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    try {
        log.debug("Should fetch document with reference " + reference);

        elkomRemote = ejbClientHelper.getElkomRemote();
        DataHandler dh = ejbRemote.fetchDocument(reference);
        if(dh == null) {
            throw new SOAPException();
        }
        return dh;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.fatal(Consts.NAMING_EXCEPTION, e);
        throw new SOAPFaultException();
    } catch (PropsFileException e) {
        log.fatal(Consts.PROPS_FILE_EXCEPTION, e);
        throw new SOAPFaultException();
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        log.error("SOAPException", e);
        throw new SOAPFaultException();
    } 
}
}
```

This is a maven project, and before the update I used the weblogic libraries for handling ejb + JAX-WS RI 2.2.5. Now after the update, weblogic force the use of JAX-WS RI 2.2.10-b140319.1121. Is this version broken?

Response from webservice running WebLogic 11g:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
  <ns2:fetchDocumentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://my.services.example.com">
     <return>
        <xop:Include href="cid:58eaad0c-4723-44c0-bada-4d9bd237b935@example.jaxws.sun.com" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
     </return>
  </ns2:fetchDocumentResponse >
```

Document was in an attachment.

Response running WebLogic 12c

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
  <ns0:hentDokumentResponse xmlns:ns0="http://my.services.example.com">
     <return>SUkqADRTAAAAgLJIAICgAgLJIAICySAC ...</return>
  </ns0:hentDokumentResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Edit:
Weblogic 11g used Java EE 6, and 12c is using Java EE 7. Java version:

java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Document is only a base64encoded String. We need it to be like before... Anyone else had this problem? And found a solution?

Comment: `12c is using Java EE 7` - This is not entirely correct. WLS 12.1.1 to 12.1.3 are Java EE 6. The next 12.x (likely 12.2.1) will be Java EE 7.

Comment: Okey, it is not fully Java EE 7 certified yet. Have created a ticket at Oracle, but they say that it seems to be working according to the specification. Ticket is still not solved at this time.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what they changed in WLS12c, but we had the same exact problem. Solution for us was to use Accept header on client:

`mimeHeaders.setHeader("Accept", "application/xop+xml;");`

Trace:

- @Mtom "threshold" on server didn't make any change
- replacing message factory with axis2 and forcing "setProcessMTOM(true)" didn't make any change
- plain SOAP clients (MessageFactory/SoapMessage) works fine with Accept header -> response via xop:Include
- jaxws client works without any change

Anyone link to ticked mentioned by @baron5